# FTP up site using without uploading .svn files tortoise svn

Tags: svn, ftp, tortoisesvn

I'm using tortoise SVN and want to FTP my site up. However when I do this it includes all the .svn files. I don't want to upload these. How can I setup the Core FTP LE filter to ignore these files on upload?

Or is there a way using tortoise SVN to check out a clean copy of my repository without any .svn folders?

Or is there any handy batch files out there which will delete the .svn files?

Thanks!

Ben.

Comment: Hello, I solved this using the guide here: http://www.sean-barton.co.uk/2009/07/how-to-recursively-remove-svn-directories/ This guide shows you how to create a handy batch file which deletes all the .snn files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Tortoise SVN, you can "Export" (right click option) your repository, which removes all the meta files.

http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/nightly/TortoiseSVN_en/apc.html

^^ Covers the command line options for TortoiseSVN.